# Is AsyncStorage intended for repeated calls

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have more of a conceptional question..hopefully that is okay.

Is AsyncStorage ment for repeated calls? For example... I have an application with a slideshow which I want the user to be able to remeber where in the slideshow they were each time they open the app.

I was thinking of using AsyncStore to update the index on it each time it switches slides.. but am worried that means I cam accessing it too much and constantly resetting the index. Is that over the top or is that use in a way of how it is intended to be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you send you code dump,

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is totally okay. I use AsncStorage also for a Slider-Component and save its value to asncStorage after each change-event. But i've bounced it to only one write within 500 ms (the last write will win here).

If you plan to store bigger documents, you should consider, that internally the AsyncStorage stores all keys and values within one huge file. Depending on the overall size it could be get slow and battery consuming then.

Comment: hmm thats a good point.. im hoping like maybe 10 different fvalues in a file won't slow it down? i m mean thats nothing in the grand scheme of things

Comment: Or else try to save the current slide as a state and call the async storage during on componentwillunmount call the asyncstorage and save it